# Query on all the people who has watched the same movies as I did

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let say I have watched more than one movie, how do I find out all the people who also watched all the movies I watched?

```
     MovID  Name   Movie name
    ---------------------
    1     | me     |Batman
    2     | me     |Spider Man
    1     | Jason  |Batman
    2     | Jason  |Spider Man
    3     | Jason  |King kong 
    3     | Jim    |King kong
    4     | Jim    |Titanic
```

Which the result should give me Jason. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
select name
  from tbl
 where movid in (select movid from tbl where name = 'me')
   and name <> 'me'
 group by name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from tbl where name = 'me')
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3120e/2/0