# Query all users who have watched the same movies in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a simple query that I need to execute which will return all users who have watched the same movies, the date they did so and the number of times each movie was watched. The result should be grouped by movie title.

Say I have movie title: Gladiator and Prometheus. The result should be like:

1. Gladiator: Watched: 10 times| by: Alan, Bruce, Cecil, Marlon, etc| on: 10/01/2020, 1/11/2019,  etc
2. Prometeus: Watched: 7 times| by: Julia, Baner, Alan, Marlon, etc | on: 10/01/2020, 1/11/2019,  etc

I have MOVIE table, USER table, VIEW table

Some infos that might help you understand my problem:

- MOVIE has view count row
- VIEW has date row
- USER has name, etc

My question is a bit similar to this: [Query on all the people who has watched the same movies as I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934835/query-on-all-the-people-who-has-watched-the-same-movies-as-i-did) but I wasn't able to adapt the solution to my case.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi. although it should be not too complicated, we can't help you without minimal code you did, tabe structure etc. please add information to your question

Comment: "all users who have watched the same movies" doesn't make sense. One can expect difficulties in trying to reason & communicate about a query returning what's wanted if that's where one stopped trying to write clearly. When clear this will be a faq. PS Such an "all" starting what rows are wanted is unneeded & is easily confused with other uses of "all". PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Please: Show what parts you can do. In code questions give a [mre].

Comment: @ShirGans The table structure is as simple as what I already included in my initial question

Comment: Put everything needed to ask a question in the question, not just at a link. Anyway your other post has no [mre] either. That includes cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.[help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the following table structures:

```
movie: movie_name, view_count
user: user_name, age, city
view: movie_name, user_name, view_date
```

The query can be:

```
select m.movie_name as movie, 
       m.view_count as watched, 
       listagg(v.user_name, ',') as by, 
       listagg(v.view_date) as on
from   movie m, view v
where  m.movie_name = v.movie_name
group  by m.movie_name, m.view_count;
```

Group by function `listagg` is available in Oracle's SQL. Microsoft's SQL has similar `string_agg`, in MySql `group_concat` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The view table has user_id instead and view has movie_id too

Comment: Tried to adapt to my query but wasn't able to. Your example doesn't take in account the fact we have to pass movie_name in the query